# React Native: how do you deal with graphics making time etc at the top of the screen hard to see?

Tags: react-native, statusbar, uistatusbar, react-native-image

I have the following graphic at the top of the screen in my React Native app:

[image]

Obviously the problem is that the time, battery power, etc, are hard to see because the graphic is black. How do people normally deal with this kind of thing? If I made it white, I'd run the risk of it being less visible if the time etc on a particular phone is white. Should I just put padding at the top of the screen so that the graphic doesn't overlap with the text?

Comment: use SafeAreaView

Answer (score 0):

If you know the color of the graphic of each page, and have a limited number of pages, just hard-code it.
You can set the color of status bar text with https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#setbarstyle. Call this on every page on focus to make sure it's right.

If the graphic is dynamic, grab the dominant color with https://github.com/iran-react-community/rn-dominant-color. Then, you can use the https://github.com/Qix-/color to determine whether the color is light or dark, and set it accordingly with StatusBar.setBarStyle API.

Just my quick thoughts.